# parsing a value and then convert it to specific type

Tags: c++, parsing, types

```
Datatype: INT8
Value: -8

Datatype: INT32
Value: 12540

Datatype: FLOAT
Value: 12.45                                                                 configfile.cfg
```

I want to read entries out of a configfile.

```
long double n;
ignore("Value:");
read_number(n);
addEntry(datatype, n);                                                           Parser.cpp
```

addEntry(std::string, long double) needs the value to initialize the parameter.

```
void addEntry(std::string s, long double n)
{
   if(s == "BOOL")
   {
        param.SetValue((BOOL)n);
   }
   ..
   else if(s == "FLOAT")
   {
        param.SetValue((FLOAT)n);
   }
   ..
}                                                                            Repository.cpp
```

Is it typesafe to read the values in a long double variable and then convert it to the specific datatype in my case?

The Values which can be written in the configfile are: BOOL, UINT8, UINT16, UINT32, INT8, INT16, INT32, FLOAT.

Comment: What is the type of `param`? Also, how did you define `BOOL` and `FLOAT`?

Comment: consider keeping the value a string until  dataype is requested with a typed function call, for example, `int32 getint32()`. If the string cannot be converted, throw an exception. this will save you from creating an object hierarchy or a union and have to create the getType functions anyway.

Comment: @user4581301 thanks i will take this solution. If you post this as an answer to the question, i will accept the answer.